# How to get max from PARTITION BY Clause using CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
WITH ABC AS 
    (
        SELECT ACCOUNTID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNTID ORDER BY ACCOUNTID) AS NUMBER FROM BankRequest
    )

    SELECT * FROM ABC
```

## Current Query give me output like below

```
    ACCOUNTID   NUMBER
    897         1
    897         2
    897         3
    1110        1
    1110        2
    1110        3
    1110        4
    1119        1
    1119        2
    1119        3
    1119        4
    1146        1
    1146        2
    1182        1
    1395        1
    1395        2
    1395        3
    1395        4
    1395        5
```

## Expected output would be like

```
    ACCOUNTID   NUMBER
    897         3
    1110        4
    1119        4
    1146        2
    1182        1
    1395        5
```

I am using SQL 2016 and trying achieve get multiple record from  BankRequest table. In this table each accountid having multiple record as i mentioned above first table. but i want only last transaction id for each accountid from  BankRequest table.

Please help me for this problem or any better alternative way where i can achieve expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Two quick options in the final select

```
Select AccountID,Number=max(number) 
 From  ABC 
 Group By AccountID
```

**Or**

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  ABC
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By AccountID Order By Number Desc)
```

**Or eliminate the CTE**

```
Select AccountId
       Number = count(*)
 From  BankRequest
 Group By AccountId
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use your same cte and get Number = 1 as below:

```
;WITH ABC AS 
(
    SELECT ACCOUNTID,NUMBER, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNTID ORDER BY Number DESC) AS RowN FROM BankRequest
)
SELECT ACCOUNTID, NUMBER FROM ABC
where RowN = 1
```

This is similar to top 1 with ties which John mentioned

Comment: Fixed that issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY AccountID DESC`, and select where the row number is 1.

However, I'm thinking that you gave us an incomplete data set.

"i want only last transaction id for each accountid" means you should probably really `ORDER BY transactionId DESC`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CTE + Row_Number() + Max()` like below one

```
;WITH BankRequest_Row_Number_By_ACCOUNTID
AS
(
    SELECT  ACCOUNTID, 
            Row_NUmber() over (Partition by ACCOUNTID order by ACCOUNTID) AS rowNumber_ACCOUNTID
    FROM    BankRequest

)
SELECT  ACCOUNTID,
        MAX(rowNumber_ACCOUNTID) AS NUMBER
FROM    BankRequest_Row_Number_By_ACCOUNTID
GROUP BY ACCOUNTID
```